# What does strvar db "hello" means in Assembly?

Tags: assembly

Does processor allocates 1 byte for each character of the String?
If yes then is allocating 1 byte enough for character as ASCII values vary from 0-255?

Comment: Yes and yes.  A byte can have a value between 0 and 255, so of course the space is sufficient.  `db` stands for “data byte” as far as I know.

Comment: You should include your code sample in the question itself, and remember to format it correctly by indenting 4 spaces.

Comment: YesNo... many assemblers use still ASCII encoding by default, which is exactly 1 character = 1 byte (and ASCII is well defined for values 0..127, of those 32..126 being printable characters, values 128-255 are platform specific). Some assemblers (NASM in linux for example) support UTF-8 encoding, which is variable width character encoding, 1 character is 1..4 bytes long code-point, but as long as you use ordinary ASCII characters, you will get 1 char = 1 byte even in UTF-8, which has identical encoding for the ASCII subset of glyphs. There're hundreds of other string encodings possible.

Comment: And some letter may compose together in some languages, for example in Hindi "दें" is UTF-8 encoded as bytes `e0 a4 a6 e0 a5 87 e0 a4 82`, unfortunately I don't understand Hindi to decompose it into separate characters and search for their particular bytes code-points. Keep in mind `db` is "define byte" directive, so whatever complex argument you use (like string), assembler has to turn it into machine code (bytes), the ability to define string with quotes is sort of convenience feature of assembler, diverting from original `db` meaning. Check the listing after compilation to see machine code.

Comment: Your assembler takes the bytes between the quotes of the string as is. That is, using whichever character encoding you used with your editor. It does not need to interpret the string as text so it just copies the bytes. Of course, it has to interpret the rest of the source file so you must use an encoding that it understands. Different assemblers have different source encoding features. People as always saying they are using ASCII (0-127). That just hasn't been true in the PC world. Their editors, assemblers, OSes, BIOSes, etc have all used some other encoding that happens to be a superset.

Answer (score 3):

The *processor* is not allocating anything. The directive

```
strvar:
    db "hello"
```

Tells the assembler to emit the bytes "hello" at a location in your program identified by the label `strvar`.

A byte is usually 8 bits, which can store the unsigned values 0 to (2<sup>8</sup> - 1) = 255.